# Code Completion in Laravel Blade Templates - vscode

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade, intelephense

I really like vscode compared to phpstorm but How to get PHP Intelephense code completion to work in laravel blade templates?

```
@php

{{ $user->email }} <- autocomplete not working

@endphp
```

Comment: i like vscode alot too, but theere arent many extenstion for laravel or blade tbh, phpstorm is very good with laravel. if you want free version, check the phpstorm alpah app https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/